# Disable Gmail automatic categorisation?

Tags: gmail, gmail-categories

Gmail has an automatic categorisation feature that sorts mail into various categories (social, promotions, updates, etc.). I would like to have an "Updates" tab, but I would like to disable the automatic categorisation so that the only mail that goes into this category is mail that I set up a filter for.

I currently have my mail going into a label, but labels aren't quite as nice as the tabs that categories have.

Is there a way to prevent mail automatically being assigned to a category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to prevent mails from being automatically assigned to a category. You can [disable tabs](https://www.quora.com/Gmail/How-can-I-disable-Gmails-new-tabbed-inbox-June-2013/answer/Franck-Dernoncourt?share=1) though.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using multiple inboxes.

1. Create a filter and label for those messages. Call the label `updates`
2. Enable the multiple inboxes option via Gear button/Settings/labs.
3. Under settings/multiple inboxes set the top box as "is:updates"
4. Click save changes.

Options on that page also let you position the inbox and set the number of messages to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

After years of despising this "feature", I finally found a solution.

- Go to Settings -> See All Settings
- Go to the "Filters and Blocked Addresses".
- "Create a New Filter"
- Make the search criteria "Greater than 1 Byte" (all messages will match this filter)

[image]

- Set the filter to "Categorize as Primary"

[image]

It's been a few weeks now and not a single message has skipped my inbox. All the Categories are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Give this filter a try:

```
category:updates -label:LABEL_NAME
```

Set it up so that the `Has Words` filter option has the above text in it, and then have it so that the assigned category for anything without the label is something like `Personal`. Essentially this filter will look in the category updates, and anything without the specified label is selected. You use the filter to move these emails to a different category. As long as they have the correct label they will not be moved.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: filter params]

[image: filter settings]

Answer (score -1):

Use the following filters in your filter settings:

> Matches: "your email address"@gmail.com,
> Do this: Skip Inbox, Never send it to Spam,

Never mark it as important, Categorize as Primary