# How to completely disable Gmail categories and see all messages in inbox?

Tags: gmail, gmail-categories

I would like to configure Gmail to behave like a traditional email service where my incoming messages all appear in my inbox by default. I don't want them sorted into "social", "updates", "forums", and "promotions" categories. I don't mind if Gmail wants to discreetly do that *in addition*, so long as I will definitely see all my messages when I go to my inbox.

Unfortunately I do not seem to be able to achieve that behaviour, and Gmail behaves very inconsistently. I've already disabled categories in the settings:

[image: Settings screenshot]

That has resulted in the removal of category tabs at the top of the page and what *appears on the surface* to be a unified inbox view. However, I can still see the categories on the left-side menu:

[image: Categories screenshot]

That would be fine, except that I'm observing the following inconsistent behaviour:

1. Messages will sometimes appear in my inbox but not a category
2. Messages will sometimes appear in a category but not my inbox
3. Messages will sometimes appear in my inbox **and** a category.

Often the above messages will be very similar looking ones from the same sender, making the behaviour seem almost random. When I click on "all mail" it appears that some messages are being tagged with an "inbox" label while others are not:

[image: All mail screenshot]

My Google searches reveal that this is a common problem but not one that I've been able to find any solution for. For example, [see here](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/12283642/how-to-i-disable-categories-i-don-t-want-mail-to-go-into-various-categories?hl=en) and note how heavily downvoted the answers are which claim that disabling categories in the settings is a solution.

**What do I need to do to have a 100% guarantee that I will see all non-spam messages when I click on my inbox in Gmail?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54107/88163

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after I posted my question, I found the solution in point number 4 on the answer on [this page](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/28326014/emails-not-labelled-with-inbox-are-not-showing-in-my-inbox-only-in-all-mail?hl=en):

> Hi Stacey, there are four places that the Inbox label can be removed.
>
> 1 - [...]
>
> 4 - If another device (e.g. mobile phone) is connected to your account
> using IMAP, archiving messages in that device will remove them from
> your Inbox.

After some experimenting, I've discovered that the Android Gmail app is configured to ["archive"](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) rather than delete your emails when you swipe left or right. Archiving an email causes the inbox label to be removed but leaves a copy in the categories (if any) and otherwise removes it everywhere except "all mail". The fix is to change the settings in the Android app:

3 dots menu -> Settings -> General settings -> Swipe actions -> Change "Right swipe" and/or "Left swipe" to the "Delete" action